# I want to filter out a non-numeric value and calculate it's new value using two other columns in the dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a `df` that looks something like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.8 | 0.1 | SP |
| 0.9 | 0 | SP |
| 0.9 | 0.1 | SP |
| 0.7 | SP | 0.2 |
| 0.9 | SP | 0 |

I want to replace the SP values in `col3` by using the values from `col1` and `col2` to sum to 1, I also want to do this using col2.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

I thought it would look something like this, but this is clearly wrong.

`df['col3'] = df['col3'].replace(to_replace= "SP", value= (1 -df['col1'] - df['col2'])`

Comment: The error in your approach is that you try to add a number with a string: 1+'SP'. So, you should filter it before.
See rows 4 and 5 in column 'col2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look like no reliable code, but still it could help.

`df[df['col3']=='SP']` do the same as `df.loc[df['col3']=='SP']`, but `'df.loc'` should be better for assigning. (when you try without .loc it will recommend use it for assign)

The code filter the rows where SP is in column 3, then assign.

```
df['col3'].loc[df['col3']=='SP']=1-df['col1'][df['col3']=='SP']-df['col2'][df['col3']=='SP']
```

### EDIT

*Alternatives: [5 ways to apply an IF condition in Pandas DataFrame](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/#:%7E:text=Applying%20an%20IF%20condition%20in%20Pandas%20DataFrame&text=You%20then%20want%20to%20apply,assign%20the%20value%20of%20%27False%27)

```
df['col3']=df.apply(lambda x: 1-x['col1']-x['col2'] if x['col3'] == 'SP' else x['col3'],axis=1)
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I am looking for, thank you! I have one more question, I have noticed my data has formatted strangely, where I was expecting values in float form, i.e. `0.8`, I instead have, `80%` which pandas is interpreting as a string, would you know how to get around this? It is very straight forward if all values in the column are formatted this way, but because my column contains strings such as the one above, I cannot use the regular method which would be: `df[col2] = pd.to_numeric((df[col2].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100), errors='coerce')`

Comment: to apply `.str.method` you need each element to be a string, so use `df[col2].astype(str).str.rstrip('%')`